# DataList render rows as columns

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Hi i want to force DataList to render rows as columns, where first column is rows description. I can not use repeater cos i want to `edit and update data`. I started with that but it works compleatly wrong:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Name" >
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table style="border:1">
                        <tr><td>Name</td>
                        <tr><td>FirstName</td>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' ID="Code" ReadOnly="true" /> </td>
                           <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>' ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="true" /> </td>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <FooterTemplate>
                       </tr>
                       </tr>
                        </table>
                       </FooterTemplate>

                       </asp:DataList>
```

I could use only this

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1"  runat="server" DataKeyField="Name" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >                       
                        <ItemTemplate>                        
                           <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' ID="Code" ReadOnly="true" />
                           <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>' ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="true" />
```

and then i am missing only firs column with labels, how could i add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a table. Let each item be a list item and put your controls in there. You can then float each list item left.

Comment: Your Header could be a <ul> and your footer could be a </ul> Each Item Template could hold an <li> tag with your server controls inside. You'll probably want to set a width for the <li> tags and have them float left. You could do search for displaying list items as columns.

Comment: what? but this is rendered as table, c;mon

Comment: hmmm.. i wonder if you could get away with what you were trying with display = vertical. Then maybe you could wrap the whole thing in a table and put a column in for your labels. It doesn't seem that clean--- but it might work.

Comment: see what the output of the html is. You might be able to do it with the headerTemplate and have a table with multiple rows for each label.